# React-Native-Webview: Expected nodeHandle to be not null

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I am using `react-native-webview` for rendering a webview. When I navigate from one page to other inside the webview and then try to go back using `this.webviewref.goBack()` I get the exception of `nodeHandle expected to be non-null`.

Here is my piece of code

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Header
          headingText={headerText}
          onpress={() => {
            // this.dispatchCustomEvent(BACK_PRESS);
            if (this.canGoBack) {
              this.webViewRef.goBack();
            } else NavigationActions.pop();
          }}
        />
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: "http://localhost:3001/invite/" }}
          bounces={false}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          ref={webViewRef => (this.webViewRef = webViewRef)}
          // injectedJavaScript={patchPostMessageJsCode}
          onMessage={event => {
            const { type, data } = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
            console.log({ type });
            console.log({ data });
            this.handleEvent(type, data);
          }}
          onNavigationStateChange={navState =>
            (this.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack)
          }
        />
      </View>
```

console logging `this.webViewRef` shows that the `goBack` method exists in the weViewRef

The code for which throws the `nodeHandle expected to be non-null` can be found here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/src/WebView.ios.tsx

I am unable to understand what is the problem with `getWebViewHandle`
and why `nodeHandle` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turns out that my react-native version is too low. It requries at least 0.57. After upgraded to 0.59.5 and other dependencies, this problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem too and I found a solution, my solution at leasts.
I had this piece code:

Versions:
`"react": "16.11.0"`
`"react-native": "0.62.2"`
`"react-native-webview": "^9.4.0"`

```
<WebView
     ref={this._setWebviewRef}
     onNavigationStateChange={this._handleWebViewNavigationStateChange}
     onMessage={this._handleOnMessage}
     source={{uri: this.state.dashboardUrl || ''}}
     renderLoading={() => <LoadingSpinner />}
     startInLoadingState
     incognito
/>
```

where `this._setWebviewRef` was the next:

```
_setWebviewRef = (ref) => {
    if (ref && !this.props.webviewRef) {
      const {goBack} = ref;
      goBack && this.props.setWebviewRef({goBack});
    }
};
```

I'm using `redux` to save `goBack` method to use it on the typic `_handleAndroidBackButton`. So as other guys said, i was giving the fu***** `nodeHandle expected to be non-null` but i was seeing that goBack method exists on `_handleAndroidBackButton` context.
Debugging i saw that `ref` WebView method has multiple calls, not just 1 time as i was controlling. So, deleting this condition `&& !this.props.webviewRef` is already working.

Also, I had tried to set my uri 'hardcoded' with the same error, so that not work for me.

PD: don't try to save entire WebView ref on global state, just save what you need our you will have some errors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem may be that your component has been rendered for a certain condition at the beginning, but after the condition is not satisfied, the modified component is removed, but the reference of the component is not empty. Therefore, when calling the component method, the component method is called, because the component is not empty, but the reference is still not empty, resulting in an error. To adjust the error caused by the above situation, just set the variable referenced by the previous assignment to null when removing the component